# Send data from main activity listview to detail activity with fragment using Tab Layout

Tags: android

I am new in Android Development and I don't know how to pass data from main activity with Listview to select particular product and go to new activity with fragement tablayout...I want to know how can I get data in fragment tablayout from main activity...Thanks

MainActivity.java

  *import packages...*

```
  public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  String s_firstname, s_lastname, s_password, s_email, Err;
  TextView fname,lname,email,password,err,sid;
  private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
  private Toolbar toolbar;
  private ListView lv;
  private List<String> classList;
  private FloatingActionButton fab;
  Context ctx=this;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initNavigationDrawer();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    SharedPreferences ui = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s_id = ui.getString("s_id","s_id");
    new SignupActivity(this).execute(s_id);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String c_name = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,ClassDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("c_name", c_name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,JoinclassActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

DetailsProduct.java

```
public class ClassDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_details);
    String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("c_name");
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new  ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new EventFragment(), "Event");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
  }
}
```

OneFragement.java

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {
TextView tv;

public EventFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link. There showed how to pass value to the viewpager fragment.

[Send values from ViewPager Activity to a Fragment by bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727759/send-values-from-viewpager-activity-to-a-fragment-by-bundle)