# how to pass Same values from main activity to all fragment Trough view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created this sliding tabs with fragments using viewpager but i need to pass some data let's say id to all the fragments from parent activity how can this be accomplished please help

Main activity. Here the sliding tabs activity is created and fragments are loaded -

```
public class SimpleTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_tabs);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Category-1");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Category-2");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Category-3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }



    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

}
}
```

example fragment code -

```
 public class OneFragment extends Fragment{


public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send values from ViewPager Activity to a Fragment by bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727759/send-values-from-viewpager-activity-to-a-fragment-by-bundle)

Comment: @DimaKozhevin my usage of view pager is different